# Solving second order DE's with respect to parametric equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, differential-forms

I am looking at the motion of particles in force fields (so acceleration). With a given vector acceleration

$$\vec{a}(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
P(x,y)  \\ Q(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}
\textrm{with initial velocity }
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{x_0}  \\ v_{y_0}
\end{bmatrix}
\textrm{and position}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\ y_0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

I have the system of second order differential equations

$$
x^{\prime\prime}(t)=P(x(t),y(t))
$$
$$
y^{\prime\prime}(t)=Q(x(t),y(t)).
$$

This isn't too hard to solve for simple acceleration components, but how would I approach, for example, a system such as

$$
x^{\prime\prime}(t)=\sin(y(t))
$$
$$
y^{\prime\prime}(t)=-2x(t)+y(t)\textrm{ }?
$$

Comment: I doubt that this problem has a nice analytical solution. Solve it numerically. Also, try to make some approximations. For example, if $y(t)$ is small, then $\sin(y(t))\approx y(t)$.